# Subclassing pandas.Index

Tags: subclass, pandas

I would like to write a subclass of `pandas.core.index.Index`. I'm following the guide to subclassing ndarrays which can be found in the [numpy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#a-brief-python-primer-on-new-and-init). Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class InfoIndex(pd.core.index.Index):

    def __new__(subtype, data, info=None):
        # Create the ndarray instance of our type, given the usual
        # ndarray input arguments.  This will call the standard
        # ndarray constructor, but return an object of our type.
        # It also triggers a call to InfoArray.__array_finalize__
        obj = pd.core.index.Index.__new__(subtype, data)
        # set the new 'info' attribute to the value passed
        obj.info = info
        # Finally, we must return the newly created object:
        return obj
```

However, it doesn't work; I only get a `Index` object:

```
In [2]: I = InfoIndex((3,))

In [3]: I
Out[3]: Int64Index([3])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index constructor tries to be clever when the inputs are special (all ints or datetimes for example) and skips to calls to view at the end. So you need to put that in explicitly:

```
In [150]: class InfoIndex(pd.Index):
   .....:     def __new__(cls, data, info=None):
   .....:         obj = pd.Index.__new__(cls, data)
   .....:         obj.info = info
   .....:         obj = obj.view(cls)
   .....:         return obj
   .....:     

In [151]: I = InfoIndex((3,))

In [152]: I
Out[152]: InfoIndex([3])
```

Caveat emptor: be careful subclassing pandas objects as many methods will explicitly return Index as opposed to the subclass. And there are also features in sub-classes of Index that you'll lose if you're not careful.

Comment: This no longer seems to work, I still get an pd.Index as output.

Answer (score 3):

If you implement the `__array_finalize__` method you can ensure that metadata is preserved in many operations. For some index methods you'll need to provide implementations in your subclass. See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html for a bit more help

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the previous answers. You can also preserve most index methods, if you use the `_constructor` property and set `_infer_as_myclass = True`.